# MySQL and Python printing issues

Tags: python

I have just started studying MySQL and Python and I have an error which I cannot fix.

This is my code

```
import MySQLdb

conn = MySQLdb.connect("Donata.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com",
                       user, password, db)

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("SELECT * FROM taula")

rows = c.fetchall()

for EachRow in rows:
   print EachRow
```

And after I run I have a following error

```
   File "/home/Donata/donatapython.py", line 12
     print EachRow
                 ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Could someone explain me what is incorrect here?

Comment: Are you using python 3? If so you need to write `print(EachRow)`

Comment: Don't include usernames/passwords in your code examples

Comment: Thank you RoberB, very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the variable in a parenthesis. Instead of the loop you used, try this.

```
for EachRow in rows:
  print(EachRow)
```

You should also set the values of the host, user, password, and database. Use 'passwd' instead of 'password'.